# Enable keepalive or connection reuse in forward proxy

Tags: proxy, haproxy, keepalive

I need to setup a **forward** proxy in this way:

`application server ---> forward proxy ---> internet (every site from internet)`

For example: `curl --proxy http:my-proxy.com:8080 https://google.com`

It does not matter if the forward proxy server is nginx, apache, haproxy or other.

I can configure them easily, but I have one problem:

**How can I configure HTTP keepalive / connection re-use / persistent connection from the forward proxy server to the internet sites (if they support and return HTTP 1.1 or Connection: Keep-Alive)?**

The problem is that without persistent connections my forward proxy **opens TCP socket connections for every request** and **therefore makes SSL handshakes for every request** for https sites.

I want to benefit from latency with persistent connections.

I want my proxy to behave like an ordinary web browser client: if the server supports connection re-use, my proxy to establish persistent connection with the server (for the time the remote internet server allows, for example 60 seconds).

**How can I do this in Linux with nginx, apache, haproxy or other proxy software which you can suggest to me?**